# Cannot run cap production deploy:initial with Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, ssh, capistrano

I tried to deploy my rails app from my mac into the server on digital ocean (using github).

So when i ran `cap production deploy:initial` for the firstime i got this error

```
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke rvm:hook (first_time)
** Execute rvm:hook

cap aborted!
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user deploy@myip

/Users/manjarb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.0.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:250:in `start'
/Users/manjarb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `call'
/Users/manjarb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `with'
/Users/manjarb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:155:in `with_ssh'
/Users/manjarb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:108:in `execute_command'
/Users/manjarb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
/Users/manjarb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `tap'
/Users/manjarb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `create_command_and_execute'
/Users/manjarb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:55:in `test'
/Users/manjarb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-rvm-0.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/manjarb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
/Users/manjarb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
/Users/manjarb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sshkit-1.11.5/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
```

But I already added my server `id_rsa.pub` to repository Deploy Key.
And when i test by cloning my repo from ssh key it works fine without any problem.

this is my `deploy.rb`

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock "3.7.1"

set :repo_url,        'git@github.com:myrepo.git'
set :application,     'appname'
set :user,            'deploy'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
end
```

So how can i fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a ruby or capistrano user, but:

```
set :ssh_options,     { ..., keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You should specify the private key file here, not the public key file. The private key file is probably "~/.ssh/id_rsa" without the ".pub" extension.